# Отображение лога на экране .NET 4 C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Всем привет. Подскажите, каким образом лучше реализовать отображение лога на экране? 
Лог выводится в виде текста в режиме реального времени во время работы программы.

Пробовал обычный RichText, но после 2-3тыщ строк текста он начинает жутко тупить. 
Строки добавляются в конец и курсор переводит на последнюю строку.
И на обработку 40тыщ записей из БД (2-3 записи в лог на 1 запись из БД) уходит 6-7 часов. 
Без вывода на экран - обработка занимает 58 минут.

Comment: RichTextBox действительно не приспособлен для работы с большими текстами. Но вы уверены, что с таким объемом записей в логе этот лог вам действительно нужен? Там же не найти ничего будет, по крайней мере без поиска. Возможно имеет смысл логировать все в файл, а в UI выводить только критические записи (ошибки, например).

Comment: Ну и если хочется остаться при своем, то покажите код. Строки иммутабельны, и работа с ними может съесть очень много памяти, например, тем самым замедляя работу.

Comment: В файл и так логируется.
А вообще, да, думал над таким. На экран выводить только необходимые записи.

Comment: Думаю, по этому пути в любом случае нужно идти. UI нужен для пользователя. А пользователю не нужна сотня тысяч строк, ему нужна важная краткая информация: ошибки, количество обработанных записей и т.д.

Answer (score 5):

System.Windows.Forms.ListView + ListView.VirtualMode позволяет работать с большими объёмами данных для отображения.

Answer (score 2):

Большое количество записей можно быстро выводить в DataGridView.
Ниже пример, в котором выводится **500 тысяч** строк и через каждые 50 ms в лог добавляется новая запись.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
// Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.0.51204
#r "System.Windows.Forms"

using System.Windows.Forms;

static DataGridView LogView(int columns) {
    var g = new DataGridView() {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        RowHeadersVisible = false,
        ColumnHeadersVisible = false,
        AutoGenerateColumns = false,
        AllowUserToAddRows = false,
        AllowUserToDeleteRows = false,
        GridColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke,
        AllowUserToResizeRows = false,
        VirtualMode = true
    };
    for (var i=0; i < columns; i++) g.Columns.Add("c" + i, "");
    g.Columns[columns-1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    return g;
}
```

---

```
class LogRow { public int RowId; public object Data; }

var logui = LogView(2);

// по-запросу возвращаем значения, необходимые для вывода в ui
logui.CellValueNeeded += (s, e) => {
    var row = log[e.RowIndex];
    switch(e.ColumnIndex) {
       case 0: e.Value = row.RowId; break;
       case 1: e.Value = row.Data; break;
    }
};

var f = new Form() { Width = 800, Height = 300 };
f.Controls.Add(logui);

// загружаем 500 тыс. записей
var log = Enumerable
          .Range(0, 500000)
          .Select(i => new LogRow { RowId = i, Data = DateTime.Now.Ticks })
          .ToList();
logui.RowCount = log.Count;

// добавляем новую запись каждый 50 ms
new Timer() { Interval = 50, Enabled = true }.Tick += delegate {
    log.Add(new LogRow { RowId = logui.RowCount, Data = DateTime.Now.Ticks });
    logui.RowCount++;
    f.Text = "LOG: " + logui.RowCount;
};

f.ShowDialog();
```

---

Для компиляции кода и запуска приложения, например, в Visual Studio Community 2015 надо открыть `View - Other Windows - C# Interactive`, скопировать в него код и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Visual Studio Community 2015 - бесплатная версия, ее можно скачать [тут](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146).

Answer (score 1):

Если RichText тормозит, то можно попробовать TextBox (Multiline=true).

По опыту знаю, что лишний вывод даже на консоль тормозит процесс обработки.

Чтобы дать пользователю адекватную информацию, а не кучу бегущего текста, лучше сообщать о ходе процесса обработки в %, кол-во обработанных верно и с ошибкой записей, итд... При этом обновление интерфейса имеет смысл делать не для каждой обработанной записи, а, например, раз в 1 секунду.

Для оптимизации работы самого вашего алгоритма могу предложить:

- Работать в несколько потоков. Каждый поток может читать из базы, обрабатывать и писать результаты.
- Логи лучше писать в файл. Причем делать это пачками по N строк без общей блокировки потоков.
- Воспользоваться SqlBulkCopy для множественной вставки в базу, если это возможно.