# Виртуальный DataViewGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Я создаю внутри метода локальную переменную типа DataViewGrid и присваиваю ему в качестве свойства DataSource значение объекта DataTable. В DataTable гарантированно есть строки, но после присвоения значение Rows.Count у объекта DataViewGrid все равно равно нулю, как будто привязка данных не произошла.
Почему так происходит? Объект DataViewGrid обязательно должен быть установлен на форму и виден, чтобы операция привязки данных работала корректно?

Answer (score 1):

> Виртуальный DataViewGrid

Надо включить режим виртуализации в свойстве `VirtualMode`, указать `RowCount` и обрабатывать событие `CellValueNeeded`. Пример на C# -- [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482162/196972).

Без виртуализации DataTable можно привязать к DataGridView в свойстве DatagridView.DataSource.
Если у DataGridView столбцы определены не автоматически, то надо каждый столбец привязать к столбцам в DataTable. Пример на C# -- [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489133/196972).

Comment: В моем случае почему-то после присвоения DataSource у объекта DataGridView не появляются Columns, хотя у DataTable они есть. В чем может быть причина?